# Grunt source files are blank

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm having a problem with multiple objects in a file array. I have two groups of files I need to run through `uglify`, one is a single file that needs to be compressed, the other is a group of files. The problem is, the task keeps saying that no source files are defined. The `src` and `dest` are the same, because the files are compressed in-place - this was working previously, the problem appeared when I introduced templates. I set up a simple testing task to verify. Here is the task config:

```js
buildDir: "bin",
build: {
    test: {
        files: [
            {
                src: ["<%= buildDir %>/js/vendor.js"],
                dest: "<%= buildDir %>/js/vendor.js"
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                src: ["<%= buildDir %>/js/**/main.js"],
                dest: ["<%= buildDir %>/js/**/main.js"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here's my simple test task:

```js
grunt.registerMultiTask('build', function() {
    console.log(this.files); // Shows first object only
    console.log(this.filesSrc); // Blank
    this.files.forEach(function(file) {
        grunt.log.writeln("Src: " + file.src); // Blank
        grunt.log.writeln("Orig: " + file.orig.src); // bin/js/vendor.js
        file.src.forEach(function(filePath) {
            grunt.log.write("Checking: " + filePath);
            if (!grunt.file.exists(filePath)) {
                grunt.log.warn("Not found!");
            } else {
                grunt.log.warn("File found!");
            }
        });
        grunt.log.writeln("Dest: " + file.dest);
    });
    return false;
});
```

The second object in the files array isn't present at all inside the task, and the first one has a blank `src` property.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was changing the CWD *after* the Files object was already generated, since that happens before the task runs. If you want to have a dynamic working directory, you need to change it in one task, then call your remaining tasks after. It's amazing what a night's rest will do to clear the brain. :)